# How to indicate there is more text to scroll?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a webpage and I have quite a bit of text, so I made a text-box that you can scroll using `Overflow: auto`. My question is how could I make it more clear that you can scroll to see more? At the moment if you don't know there is more text, you're probably not going to scroll, so I was thinking of adding a small arrow that acts as a scroller, can I do this with only CSS and HTML?

```css
.container {
  width: auto;
  left: 25%;
  height: 60%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-box">
    <h2 class="">I servizi per l'editoria scolastica</h2>
    <p>
      <h4>Progettazione e supporto alla progettazione di testi scolastici e universitari:</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>elaborazione di progetti editoriali e collane
          <li>consulenza e supervisione didattica
            <li>stesura apparati operativi
              <li>supporto e consulenza agli autori</ul>

      <h4>Progettazione grafica</h4>
      <ul>Analisi progetto editoriale e confronto con i prodotti della concorrenza; individuazione dei contenuti chiave del testo in funzione della creazione di una veste grafica coerente e valorizzante; gerarchizzazione degli elementi di decodifica e creazione
        del format grafico; ideazione copertina; supervisione tecnico-artistica della produzione</ul>

      <h4>Redazione e impaginazione</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>coordinamento degli autori e degli eventuali fornitori tecnici (grafici, fotocompositori, fotostilisti), gestione della tempistica delle consegne in affiancamento all'ufficio tecnico della casa editrice
          <li>stesura di testi: didscalie, schede, esercizi
            <li>reperimento apparati (es. fonti storiografiche, brani antologici, ecc.)
              <li>editing e revisione dei testi (contenuti e registro dell'esposizione)
                <li>redazione e impaginazione
                  <li>assistenza alla produzione</ul>
      <h4>Ricerca iconografica</h4>
      <h4>Reperimento e coordinamento illustratori</h4>
      <h4>Progettzione e gestione dei contenuti di materiali on-line, multimediali per PC e per LIM</h4>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly you're asking?

Comment: What do you mean by "if you don't know there is more text, you're probably not going to scroll"? The presence of the scroll bar should be enough of an indication that there is hidden content which can be scrolled to.

Comment: on a phone/tablet or Mac with trackpack/magic mouse, the scrollbars don't show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sidsec9 mentioned the box-shadow could be a good idea, but you'll also need some js/jquery to detect the bottom of the div when scrolling:

```
.text-box-shadow {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -25px 50px -35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Add the class to your div:

```
  <div class="text-box text-box-shadow">
```

Show or hide the class when you need it:

```
$('.text-box').scroll(function()
   {
     var div = $(this);
      if (div[0].scrollHeight - div.scrollTop() == div.height())
      {
          $('.text-box').removeClass("text-box-shadow");
      }else{
          $('.text-box').addClass("text-box-shadow");
      }
   });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/om9n6nu6/

Of course if you don't like the box-shadow you just have to replace the css we have for the class .text-box-shadow.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to use the script you wrote, but it gives me an error that says:"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". I'm probably putting it in the wrong place. Should I put it in the `<head></head>` tag?

Comment: You need to link `jQuery` files in your `<head>` section

Answer (score 5):

I would add an `inset` `box-shadow` because it is eye catchy. Answer to this is purely subjective. But you can try adding this -

```
.text-box {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -25px 50px -35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```